# Google Chrome cuts notification title

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

Why does Chrome cut off this notification's title:

> [Urgent] Submit a seller proposal

Screenshot (the "proposal" word is missing):

[image: OK]

but not for this one?

> [Urgent] Submit a seller test test test test test

[image: OK]

What is the logic behind this behavior?

So far I've seen this bug on:

- Windows 10, Chrome 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10, Chrome Canary 69.0.3461.2 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Also tested on these versions/systems, works fine here:

- Linux (GNOME), Chrome 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) (probably because it uses native system notifications here)

From my experiments this only occurs when the title length is between 26 and 33 characters. Once you go 34 characters and beyond it's not truncated anymore...

Code to reproduce the bug:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function() {
    if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
        var notification = new Notification('123456789.123456789.123456789.123', {
            body: 'This is a test notification'
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Link to bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=785589 (from November 2017!)

Answer (score 0):

The [specification](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/)  does not specify the maximum lenght of the title.

--

reproduced as well on

- Windows 7: Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 7: Chrome Version 68.0.3440.33 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)